# Unir variables en PHP

Tags: php, variables, bucle-for

Hola tengo un formulario que captura algunos datos, las variables que capturar estos datos son:

```
$parentesco1 = $_POST['parentesco1'];
$edad1 = $_POST['edad1'];
$NivelAcademico1 = $_POST['NivelAcademico1'];
$ocupacion1 = $_POST['ocupacion1'];
$salario1 = $_POST['salario1'];
```

Pero es una tabla por lo que las variables estan 6 veces más solo que con sus números incrementados

```
$parentesco2 = $_POST['parentesco2'];
$edad2 = $_POST['edad2'];
$NivelAcademico2 = $_POST['NivelAcademico2'];
$ocupacion2 = $_POST['ocupacion2'];
$salario2 = $_POST['salario2'];
```

Y así hasta llegar a 6, mi pregunta es, como puedo imprimir estos datos en un for utilizando la variable del for como contador en la variable, es decir que el número de la variable aumente en base a la variable del FOR

```
for ($i=1; $i <=6 ; $i++) { 
    $imprimir = "$parentesco"."$i";
    echo "$imprimir";
};
```

Esto es lo que traté de realizar pero no se como podría realizarlo

`var_dump($_POST)` me devuleve esto:

```
array (size=29)
  'parentesco1' => string 'padre' (length=5)
  'edad1' => string '35' (length=2)
  'NivelAcademico1' => string 'bachillerato' (length=12)
  'ocupacion1' => string 'Vendedor' (length=8)
  'salario1' => string '50' (length=2)
  'parentesco2' => string 'madre' (length=5)
  'edad2' => string '58' (length=2)
  'anio2' => string 'Comerciante' (length=11)
  'salario2' => string '150' (length=3)
  'parentesco3' => string 'hermana' (length=7)
  'edad3' => string '18' (length=2)
  'NivelAcademico3' => string 'bachillerato' (length=12)
  'anio3' => string 'Maquilera' (length=9)
  'salario3' => string '200' (length=3)
  'parentesco4' => string 'tio' (length=3)
  'NivelAcademico4' => string 'bachillerato' (length=12)
  'anio4' => string 'Vendedora' (length=9)
  'salario4' => string '350' (length=3)
  'parentesco5' => string 'abuela' (length=6)
  'edad5' => string '52' (length=2)
  'NivelAcademico5' => string 'basico' (length=6)
  'anio5' => string 'NO' (length=2)
  'salario5' => string '0' (length=1)
  'parentesco6' => string 'hermano' (length=7)
  'edad6' => string '18' (length=2)
  'NivelAcademico6' => string 'no' (length=2)
  'anio6' => string 'NO' (length=2)
  'salario6' => string '0' (length=1)
  'form10' => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el resultado de un `var_dump($_POST);` para ver como vienen los datos en el POST?

Comment: Te contesté en la pregunta, no me dejaba contestar acá por el máximo de caracteres

Comment: Más o menos con la respuesta de @marco811 podrás hacer lo que quieres. Aunque como él te ha comentado, conviene que estructures mejor los datos en el origen. Si en tu POST todas las claves tuvieran el mismo nombre sin el número incremental, sería más fácil leer los datos. Los arrays (en parte) son precisamente para eso (`$_POST` es un array), para organizar datos con una misma estructura bajo la misma clave. Aquí al colocar un número incremental en cada clave del array no haces otra cosa que complicarte la vida cuando necesites usar sus datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo pude resolver!!

Answer (score 0):

Para futuros desarrollos te recomiendo utilizar los corchetes dobles en el nombre de los campos, por ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="nombre[]"  value="Andres" />
<input type="text" name="nombre[]"  value="Paco" />
```

De esta forma es mucho mas fácil extraer la información, y de esta forma tendrás un código mas limpio:

```
var_dump($_POST['nombre']); 
/*array(2) {   [0]=>   string(6) "Andres"   [1]=>   string(4) "Paco" }*/
```

Contestando a tu pregunta:

Primeramente necesitas definir los nombres de los campos que son recurrentes:

```
$campos = array("parentesco","edad","NivelAcademico","ocupacion","salario");
```

En el siguiente paso necesitamos dos bucles, el primero que se ejecute 6 veces, y el segundo que recorra la variable $campos, que se ejecutara dentro del primero

```
    for ($i=1; $i <=6 ; $i++) { 
        foreach($campos as $campo) {
            $nombre_campo = $campo . $i;
            //Se comprueba que el campo exista en la variable $_POST
            if(!array_key_exists($nombre_campo, $_POST)) continue;
            echo $nombre_campo . "; Valor: " . $_POST[$nombre_campo];
        }
    }
```